# cleartextTrafficPermitted false still allows connection Android 9 emulator using xamain

Tags: android, security, xamarin.android

Was trying to test out different config in Android's Network Security Config config XML file that is referenced from the manifest. Using a basic new app template Xamarin.Android app targeting Android 9 API 28 and a Galaxy Nexus Android 9 emulator vis VS 2019, setting either:

1. the application level manifest setting android:usesCleartextTraffic = false
2. adding a network security config file, setting the base-config or domain-config to cleartextTrafficPermitted = false and referencing that file from the manifest

In either case, attempting a test connection using HttpClient GetAsync with a Uri of http://www.mit.edu/privacy/ works perfectly fine with no errors. Calls at runtime to `NetworkSecurityPolicy.IsCleartextTrafficPermitted` return false as expected. And if I change the settings to allow cleartext via the manifest sure enough that call will return true, so the runtime is showing its in the correct "mode", the calls just arent being blocked as I would expect when cleartext false. Is the cleartext setting not enforced on emulators? Is it not enforced in Xamarin's HttpClient stack? Basically trying to block cleartext for HTTP connections and am not able to

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had the Xamarin.Android Visual Studio Project options set to Settings > options for Build > Android Build > General > HttpClient Implementation set to Default, which means HttpClient Handler which is .NET's fully managed solution. Switching to the native AndroidClientHandler allowed the cleartext settings to work as expected. [Link to MS article abt choosing a default HTTP implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos) for Xamarin.Android